# Positioning figures from subfile side by side on landscape page in amsart

Tags: floats, positioning, landscape, amsart

I'm using the `amsart` article class, and I want to position two figures that I've saved in separate subfiles side by side on a single landscape page. However, the images aren't centred, with everything aligned slightly to the right. Here's a minimal working example which shows what's going wrong:

```
% saved as "forSE" 

\documentclass[10pt,reqno,oneside,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\title{Test title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfile{forSEfig}
        \caption{caption 1}
        \label{fig:label}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \subfile{forSEfig}
        \caption{caption 2}
        \label{fig:label2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% saved as "forSEfig"

\documentclass[forSE]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{50}{?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understand you right, you have to change your `\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}` to `\begin{minipage}{.5\textheight}`, because you used environment `landscape`.  This means that now the given textheight of your document becomes the width of the new typing area ...

I show it to you in the following mwe (please see I added an command `\fbox` in your subfile to visualize the image and added option `showframe` to package `geometry` to visualise the resulting typing area):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-fig.tex}
\documentclass[forSE]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\scalebox{50}{?}}% <=========================================
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[10pt,reqno,oneside,a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% <=========================================
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\title{Test title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textheight}% <=========================================
        \centering
        \subfile{\jobname-fig}% <=========================================
        \caption{caption 1}
        \label{fig:label}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textheight}%textwidth
        \centering
        \subfile{\jobname-fig}% forSEfig
        \caption{caption 2}
        \label{fig:label2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Please see that package `filecontents` is only used to have subfiles and tex code together in one compiling MWE (therefore I renamed the called subfile).

You will get the result:

[image: both imagages side by side]

please compare it with the following title page (changed for 90 degrees):

[image: title page changed to landscape]